# Easiest way to generate dataframe out of dict and list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dict and a list:

```
d1 = {"k1": [1,2,3], "k2": [4,5,6], "k3": [3,2,1]}
l1 = ["label1", "label2", "label1"]
```

and I want to combine it together to one dataframe. each element in `l1` corresponds to one key in `d1`

desired output (pandas dataframe):

```
  key  value   label
0  k1   1     label1
1  k1   2     label1
2  k1   3     label1
3  k2   4     label2
4  k2   5     label2
5  k2   6     label2
6  k3   3     label1
7  k3   2     label1
8  k3   1     label1
```

whats the easiest and most pythonic way to get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this using `DataFrame.melt` and `Series.map` with smart use of `zipping` the list and dict keys:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.DataFrame(d1).melt(var_name='key')
df['label'] = df['key'].map(OrderedDict(zip(d1.keys(), l1)))

  key  value   label
0  k1      1  label1
1  k1      2  label1
2  k1      3  label1
3  k2      4  label2
4  k2      5  label2
5  k2      6  label2
6  k3      3  label1
7  k3      2  label1
8  k3      1  label1
```

Comment: Just a note, also to OP, that the order of `d1.keys()` is not guarantee to be sorted. So `zip(d1.keys(), l1)` may gives different outcome.

Comment: Does that matter with `Series.map` @QuangHoang ?

Comment: Not to `map`, but to `dict(zip(...))`. So you may have `k1:label2`.

Comment: True, added fix with `OrderedDict`, this should solve it, agree? @QuangHoang

Comment: Of course `OrderedDict` would fix this. But this is more of a data structure problem for OP. You wrapping `OrderedDict` around `zip(d1.keys(), l1)` wouldn't solve the randomness of `d1.keys()`.